# Decreasing the image size after Face Detection

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I tried this face detection program that uses `haarcascades` in `opencv`.I was able to get the required output (Finding the number of faces in the provided image), but there is a slight problem with the resultant image which draws rectangles around the faces.Instead of the original image the output image is a zoomed version of the original which doesn't show the entirety of it.

**Sample**

**Input**:[image]

**Output**:
[image]

So this is what the output looks like after the program is run.

The code:

```
import cv2
import sys

# Get user supplied values
imagePath = sys.argv[1]
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces in the image
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30,30)

)

print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the prompt:

```
C:\Myproject>python main.py NASA.jpg
Found 20 faces!
```

Program gives more or less the correct answer.The scale factor can be modified to get accurate results.
So my question is what can be done to get a complete image in the output?Please add any other suggestions too,I'll be thankful.
Thanks for reading!

**EDIT:**

After a suggestion i used `imwrite` and saved the output image which seems very fine,but still the displayed image after running the program remains same.

**Saved Image**-
[image]

Comment: Does it make any difference if you do: `image=cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)` rather than just `cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)`?

Comment: @fmw42 no it doesn't

Comment: Very strange to me. I do not see much different between what you did and from https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html. However, I am relatively new to these tools. Sorry, I cannot help. I will look forward to seeing how this is solved.

Comment: Have you tried to save image to file (`cv2.imwrite('tmp.jpg', image)`)? Maybe that's just `imshow` problems.

Comment: @py_ml save to which file?I placed all the images i test,in the root folder that is "Myproject" here

Comment: The processed image with added bounding boxes

Comment: @py_ml Still doesn't do anything,though the saved image in my folder seems perfect with all faces recognized.I opened it from my folder.But still the problem persists

Comment: Could you explain what is your expected output?

Comment: @py_ml I'm expecting the image from 'imshow' to be the same like the one that is saved,but don't know why im getting  a zoomed in one.

Comment: Your code does not show how the image window is created.

Comment: Maybe the image is too big to be displayed on your screen? 
Try to add
cv2.namedWindow('Faces found', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
before
cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)
That line will create resizable window

Comment: @PiotrSiekański Thank you! The default window is set to WINDOW_AUTOSIZE.I didn't knew that.Thanks for the help.You can write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image is too big to be displayed on your screen. Add: `cv2.namedWindow('Faces found', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` before `cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)` That line will create resizeable window.